# How to detect in which direction collision happened in Flutter Flame?

Tags: flutter, dart, collision-detection, game-development, flame

I have a video game where I can move in 4 directions: up, down, left, and right. So, basically "view from above". I also have walls in the game. If the character collided with the wall - he shouldn't go through it.

How do I implement collision detection in onCollision/onCollisionStart so that character knows when he can go left, right, up, and down?

The approach that I tried:

```dart
  @override
  void onCollisionStart(
    Set<Vector2> intersectionPoints,
    PositionComponent other,
  ) {
    super.onCollisionStart(intersectionPoints, other);

    if (other is Wall) {
      // if character is going up
      if (current == MainHeroState.up) {
        upCollisionObject = other;
        return;
      }
      // if character is going down
      if (current == MainHeroState.down) {
        downCollisionObject = other;
        return;
      }
      // ...
    }
  }
```

And then in `onCollisionEnd`:

```dart
  @override
  void onCollisionEnd(PositionComponent other) {
    super.onCollisionEnd(intersectionPoints, other);

    if (other is Wall) {
      // if the link to the object is the same as the link of the collided object
      if (other == upCollisionObject) {
        upCollisionObject = null;
        return;
      }
      if (other == downCollisionObject) {
        downCollisionObject = null;
        return;
      }
      // ...
    }
  }
```

But this approach is incorrect and won't work in many cases.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.